# Forward non-www to www except for specific subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am routing all non-www requests to the www-domain by using this `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But there is one certain subdomain that I want to exclude, e.g. `blog.mydomain.tld`. How do I have to modify my condition and rule in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add that subdomain in regex of your `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|blog)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help (again)! I'm gonna reward @Lepanto as he's still in the low rep area.

Comment: Sure that is your prerogative but one should avoid repeated conditions using same variables for overall efficiency of the rule execution. Remember these rules are parsed and executed for each web request.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```